# Error when trying to get more than 200 sites using SitesApp.getAllSites

Tags: google-apps-script

In a google app script I am trying to list all the sites in a given domain, I can get the first 200 using

var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, 1, 200);

but when I try and get any more

sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, 201, 200);

I get an exception that says "Service error: SitesApp: Internal Error"  I know we have over 400 sites so I am not sure what is failing

The code looks like this

```
var domain = 'abc.com';
var start = 1;
var max = 200;

try {
    var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, start, max)
    y = sites.length; 
  } catch (e) { 
    Logger.log('Site exception: '+e);
    y=0;
  }   
if ( y != 0 ) {
process_site(sites, doc, start, y);}


try {
    var sites2 = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, 201, max)
    l = sites2.length; 
  } catch (e) { 
    Logger.log('Site2 exception: '+e);
    l = 0;
  }   
if ( l != 0 ) {
process_site(sites2, doc, 201, l);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a bug, please file an issue on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).